# How to fillReport with multi ResultSet without subreport?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I try to fill report with multi result set. But it's not working. Pleaase, give me some solution or fix my code.

```
ResultSet results1 = statement.executeQuery("FETCH ALL ret1;");
ResultSet results2 = statement.executeQuery("FETCH ALL ret2;");
JRResultSetDataSource ret1 = new JRResultSetDataSource(results1);
JRResultSetDataSource ret2 = new JRResultSetDataSource(results2);  
JasperPrint print;                                         
print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, params, ret1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably for this purpose you will need to create your own implementation of `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource`, that will be initialized with multiple data sources, in your case two.